# Excel: colour the lowest time value in range

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with times in column D, F and H. I want to color the cell with the lowest time.

[image: excel]

I have tried several things from the Conditional Formatting but it does not work.

[image: excel]

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Well, it looks like 01:28 has the lowest value.  Is that the ONE you want colored?  Need to have Specific output results example...Is the entire table as shown the Range of which you speak?  Are the value of type Time or of type String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do cannot be done with the built-in simple formats. You need to create a rule that uses a formula.

Before you do that, select the range in the worksheet. Then click **New Rule** > **Use a formula to determine**. In the screenshot that is the range from C3 to H5.

In the formula box, use a formula like this

```
=C3=MIN($C$3:$H$5)
```

Important!! The reference to C3 is **relative** to the current cell. There are no $ signs in that reference, so each cell in the range will be evaluated individually. You should use the cell at the top left of your selection. The range reference inside the MIN() function is absolute, using $ signs.

[image]

If you want to highlight the smallest value in each column, you need to create separate rules, one for each column.